# ArcMap MXD Broken

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I have an MXD that I put a lot of time and work into for cartographic purposes which unexpectedly stopped working after a reboot, and I really, really don't want to have to recreate it again from scratch if I don't have to. Chain of events and error message below...

All was fine with this MXD up until yesterday. I had started setting up the layers to display the way I want, setting up the map layout, legend, symbol levels, etc. The issue started after I added a few shapefiles from a server. The specific files and server in question, I use on a fairly regular basis and have never had issues with. The map started drawing, saving, editing, panning, etc all very slowly. I removed those recently added shapefiles, saved my work, closed everything and rebooted. Now I get this error every time I try to open the MXD:

[image: ArcMap Error]

I tried a couple different options I found by googling, including resetting the application profile, to no avail. I ran the MXD repair tool, and it found nothing corrupt, but I used it to copy my settings and layers to a new MXD anyway, which also returns the same error. Other map documents open and work just fine. I'm at a loss.

Comment: has your language/Keyboard changed from English(United States)? can your retrieve from a backup?

Comment: No, my language/keyboard are the same as they've been. I have the layers backed up, but not the mxd.

Comment: I'm sorry but I just had to laugh when I saw "Visual Fortran". Have you sent this in to ESRI support yet? I am sure they will love debugging that one.

Comment: That made me scratch my head too... I will be giving this to ESRI if I can't resolve.

Comment: If this is an issue with the shapefiles, try severing the link to those files. (disconnect from the network if those files are on the server) Hopefully the mxd will open but with all layers missing data source. Then you could remove the layers.  Also, drawing shapefiles from a server is not ideal.

Comment: recommend: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: I removed those files from the mxd before closing it.

Comment: I will try that. Edit: Just tried, no dice.

Comment: So theere are no layers in that mxd and it's still raising this error? I though you said you used MXD Doctor to transfer all unbroken, including layers. Have you tried openning the mxd on a different machine? Can you post the mxd?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21975

Comment: No, I removed only the shapefiles I had added from the server, which I assumed were causing it to run slow. It still has 20+ other layers I was using previously. I used MXD Doctor to transfer all to a new MXD, and it throws the same error. It does open on someone else's machine, with all the links broken, obviously. I cannot post it, sorry.

Comment: @Jakub I did see that when I was searching, and I have eliminated that as a potential cause.

Comment: As a last ditched attempt to recover the symbology that you spent time and effort creating you could try writing some python using arcpy to save out layer files (symbology\labelling not the data)? Search help for "Layer (arcpy.mapping)" for information on this.

Comment: Wild suggestion: try to 'repair' the ArcGIS installation. (hey, at least I'm not suggesting to re-install) This is based on an Esri forum post where the dforrt.dll needed to be replaced.

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: Did you run DocDefragmenter.exe? It compacts the mxd. It is located in the same folder as mxdDoctor.exe.

Comment: Have you tried deleting or renaming "C:\Users\%username% \AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox"?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the MXD Doctor.  He can sometimes fix things, and he's very inexpensive.
I wasn't sure if this was the same thing as the MXD repair tool you mentioned: [MXD Doctor](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31424)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you deleted your Normal.mxt from
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates

"resetting your application profile" might have already done this but it is regenerated whenever ArcMap is launched.

Comment: Yes, I already did that. That's what I meant by resetting my application profile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rename that Roaming ESRI folder to OldESRI (if you haven't done this already) and the whole folder will be regenerated, generally this is what is called a profile reset.